# How to create BaseComponent class for redux mapStateToProps

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Actually i am using redux, I have loginInfo data which i want to share across all components. One way is in every component i have to write mapStateToProps. But i don't want to do in every component. Is there any way to make base component to avail props in every component.

code:

```
class BaseComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
       super(props)
    }

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      loginInfo: state.loginInfoReducer.loginInfo
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BaseComponent)


export default class HomeComponent extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
 }
}
```

if i do like this i am getting exception 
Super expression must either be null or a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a HOC (container component) and pass all data to children
in your example :

```
function withUserData(WrappedComponent) {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent loginInfo={this.props.loginInfo} {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loginInfo: state.loginInfoReducer.loginInfo
  });

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(BaseComponent);
}
```

then in  every Components you want to use loginInfo can write this way

```
class HomeComponent extends Components {
  render() {
    return <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props.loginInfo)}</Text>;
  }
}
export default withUserData(HomeComponent);
```

Comment: your saying Inside basecomponent i will have withUserData method